# Translucent hole with center text in PieChartView

Tags: ios-charts

How to create a translucent hole and show center text together?I want to draw an entire translucent hole instead of a part. At the same time, I need to draw the center text

[Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts)

I have tried to show translucent hole using follow

```
    // draw the hole
    chartView.drawHoleEnabled = true
    chartView.holeRadiusPercent = 0
    chartView.transparentCircleRadiusPercent = 0.382
    chartView.transparentCircleColor = UIColor(red: 0.7, green: 0.7, blue: 0.7, alpha: 0.5)
    // draw the center text
    chartView.drawCenterTextEnabled = true
    chartView.centerText  = "SUM of\n3,909.00"
```

but when set the holeRadiusPercent is zero,  the center text would not draw in the hole

how could i do it?

Comment: how many dataset you are setting ?

Comment: This is not the point. I can draw the dataset correctly, but cant draw center text and translucent hole at the same time

Comment: Can you add more code related to your pia chart ? so that we can help you on that.